# "для устранения возникших проблем" - Что здесь обстоятельство?

Tags: синтаксис

> Мы рекомендуем переустановить программу для устранения возникших проблем.

Я думаю, что оборот *для устранения возникших проблем* — это нечленимое синтаксическое целое: переустановить (для чего?, с какой целью?) для устранения возникших проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Слишком радикальный подход у вас, имхо. Понятно, что все вместе "для устранения возникших проблем" - это группа обстоятельства, но почему это нечленимое целое? Нет, обстоятельство цели, как и любое другое, обычно представляет собой одно значимое слово, в данном случае это существительное в косвенном падеже ("для устранения"). 
*Другие случаи обстоятельства цели: глагол в неопределенной форме и наречие.*

А "проблем" и "возникших" - это уже дополнение и определение.

Иначе вы так сколь угодно длинную конструкцию в один член предложения запишете.

Вот здесь, посмотрите, что ли... 
http://ruslng.narod.ru/pravila/syntax/obstojatelstvo.html
http://uroki-russkogo-yazyka.ru/prostoe-predlozhenie/vtorostepennye-chleny-predlojeniya/obstoyatelstva-prichiny-i-celi.html

Хотя я даже не знаю, на что можно сослаться, когда в общем-то очевидная вещь...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы разобрала так: кто?-Мы -подлеж.что делаем? -рекомендуем-сказуемое Что рекомендуем? переустановить-дополнение; что? программу -дополнение; какую?зачем? -для устранения-определение с оттенком обст.цели ; чего?- проблем-дополнение; каких?-возникших-определение.

Для устранения -дуплексив с двунаправленной связью.Зависит одновременно от сказуемого (переустановить с какой целью?-для устранения )и от дополнения (программу какую? -для устранения).Зависит от смысла, который Вы вкладываете.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что здесь грамматический разбор связан со смыслом  предложения.

Лучше написать так: "Для устранения возникших проблем  мы рекомендуем переустановить программу (ту конкретную программу, которую уже установили)".

Тогда в начале предложения будет обстоятельственный детерминант, который относится ко всему предложению. В приведенном же примере обстоятельственную группу можно принять за определение программы (какую программу?).